# scoping problem with newcommand, renewcommand and longtable

Tags: scoping

My problem to be solved is: I want to set and reset a value (like a summation value) per line in my longtable (whose content is generated from the outside of the document).

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\newcommand{\myvalue}{initialise}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
\myvalue&test\renewcommand{\myvalue}{1}\\
test &test\renewcommand{\myvalue}{2}\\
test &test\renewcommand{\myvalue}{3}\\
test&test\renewcommand{\myvalue}{4}\\\pagebreak
\myvalue&test\renewcommand{\myvalue}{5}\\
test&test\renewcommand{\myvalue}{6}\\\pagebreak
\myvalue&test\renewcommand{\myvalue}{7}\\
test &test\renewcommand{\myvalue}{8}
\end{longtable}
This was my longtable example for \myvalue
\end{document}
```

What I expect is, that at the beginning of each page, there is a new `\myvalue` ("initialise", "4", "6") and after the table "8".

What I get is only "initialise", `\myvalue` is never changed.

https://v1.overleaf.com/17449534ktcscvntyfhy#/66313130/

Comment: Yes, this is because your redefinitions are local.

Comment: each  cell of a table is a group, `&test\renewcommand{\myvalue}{1}\\ ` is like `{test\renewcommand{\myvalue}{1}}` and the value will not be seen outside  that scope.

Comment: and how can I change that, to suit my intended behaviour?

Comment: You would have the problem with `\renewcommand` inside *any*  LaTeX environment. Tables add the compilcation that each table cell is a scope group, but the issue would be there in more friendly environments too. (as you want to use data outside the environment). LaTeX provides no interface to work around that problem. You must resort to `\global\def` or `\gdef` as in @marmot answer, or, if possible, use auxiliary files which is quite more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: use a counter, which is automatically global, and seems to be more appropriate for your purpose.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\newcounter{myvalue}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{myvalue}{0}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
\themyvalue&test\stepcounter{myvalue}\\
test &test\stepcounter{myvalue}\\
test &test\stepcounter{myvalue}\\
test&test\stepcounter{myvalue}\\\pagebreak
\themyvalue&test\stepcounter{myvalue}\\
test&test\stepcounter{myvalue}\\\pagebreak
\themyvalue&test\stepcounter{myvalue}\\
test &test\stepcounter{myvalue}
\end{longtable}
This was my longtable example for \themyvalue
\end{document}
```

As for your comment, you *could* do

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\newcommand{\myvalue}{initialise}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
\myvalue&test\global\def\myvalue{1}\\
test &test\global\def\myvalue{2}\\
test &test\global\def\myvalue{3}\\
test&test\global\def\myvalue{4}\\\pagebreak
\myvalue&test\global\def\myvalue{5}\\
test&test\global\def\myvalue{6}\\\pagebreak
\myvalue&test\global\def\myvalue{7}\\
test &test\global\def\myvalue{8}
\end{longtable}
This was my longtable example for \myvalue
\end{document}
```

If you tell us what you are ultimately after, I guess there is a more elegant way of achieving what you really want.

Comment: urgs, the "myvalue" can be everything "like EUR 20,56", the stepped counter was just to make the question simple.

Comment: So my questtion: if it is not a counter, but plain text (like "EUR") what can I use instead of setcounter?

Comment: @PeterMiehle I added something in which I make the definitions global...

Comment: what I try to achieve is an invoice, that can span many pages, and I want to put a overflow ("Übertrag EUR 570,00") at the bottom of the page and the start of the next page. The table rows are genereated from an outside source.

Comment: @marmot you can abbreviate `\global\def` to `\gdef`.

Comment: @jfbu I know, thanks! My rationale here, however, was to make explicit what the `g` stands for.

Comment: I did suspect you knew `:)`... we can delete comments if you prefer. I added one to OP.

Comment: @jfbu I appreciate your comment. Just wanted to explain why I am not changing this now unless the OP wants me to. And I also agree with your above comment, and I still don't get the purpose of all this. Why redefining a macro for something that just gets used once?

Comment: The OP wants to display it at pagebreaks, the (cumulative) values will be there. Primitive calcsheet mechanism, and your answer shows the simplest way. Probably some `\global\edef` or `\global\let` rather after the table cell has done updating of the `\myvalue` value.